# Removing Todo list Item

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove a todo list item by clicking the remove button located on the item. Im not sure how exactly to accomplish this.

The code to add the item works however the remove button function does not.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function addTodo(){
    var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    const item = `<li>
                    <div class="item">
                       <div class="complete">
                        <button id="complete" class="todo">Complete</button>
                       </div>
    
                       <p class="text">${value}</p>
    
                        <div class="remove">
                           <button id="remove" class="todo">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    </li>`;
           const position = "beforeend";
    
    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position,item);
    });
    
    document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click',function removeTodo(){
      var item = this.closest( 'li' );
        item.remove();
    });
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item"/>
    <button id="button"  type="button">Add item </button>
  </header>
  <div id="list"></div>
</div>
```

When I check the console, I get "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null   app.js:24:10"

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added it.

Comment: Also, before posting any question on StackOverflow, you should just copy/paste your error to Google and StackOverflow. The error you get has nothing new and plenty of people have already asked the same question. The goal of StackOverflow is to avoid redundant questions in order to make searches easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your code is trying to attach the event to an element that does not exist. You mus to attatch the event after you add a new item to the list.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function addTodo(){
var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
const item = `<li>
                <div class="item">
                   <div class="complete">
                    <button id="complete" class="todo">Complete</button>
                   </div>

                   <p class="text">${value}</p>

                    <div class="remove">
                       <button id="remove" class="todo">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                </li>`;
       const position = "beforeend";

list.insertAdjacentHTML(position,item);

document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click',function removeTodo(){
  var item = this.closest( 'li' );
    item.remove();
});
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item"/>
    <button id="button"  type="button">Add item </button>
  </header>
  <div id="list">
  </div>
</div>
```

Ok. This solve the initial problem, but now creates a new one: only the first item added is removed after click in the remove button.

#### Why?

First, the code is creating new buttons with the same id. In HTML the id attribute is a unique identifier to an element, for that reason they cannot be repeated.

#### Solution

add a random id a new item is created.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function addTodo(){
var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
var randomId = Math.random();
const item = `<li>
                <div class="item">
                   <div class="complete">
                    <button id="complete" class="todo">Complete</button>
                   </div>

                   <p class="text">${value}</p>

                    <div class="remove">
                       <button id="` + randomId  +`" class="todo">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                </li>`;
       const position = "beforeend";

list.insertAdjacentHTML(position,item);

document.getElementById(randomId).addEventListener('click',function removeTodo(){
  var item = this.closest( 'li' );
    item.remove();
});
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item"/>
    <button id="button"  type="button">Add item </button>
  </header>
  <div id="list">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to generate several html objects with the same id. That is why this isn't working. When your JavaScript looks for an element with the id "remove", it will find several of them, which should never happen. Also, careful about the id="complete" as well.
Try to increment your id every time you add a new todo.

Be careful though, the way you code your JavaScript is very deprecated. I would advise you to take a look at the new standards introduced in ES6 and ES7.

Comment: That adds buttons to the Header but i need them to be on the Item itself. In my JS there is a button with an Id of "remove" within the Template Literal.

Comment: I just saw the problem, I'm editing the answer. It actually comes from your JavaScript.